# If a table has no thead, should it have a tbody?

Tags: html, html-table, markup

If a `table` doesn't contain a `thead`, should the `tbody` still be included or not?

Comment: If `tbody` isn't in the source, the browser will insert it during parse (at least some browsers do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the browser's point of view, there will always exist a `tbody`, even if you don't insert it. The `tbody` is optional, unless you have a `thead` or `tfoot` tag.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not required, you can just use `<table>` and `<tr> <td>` for rows and columns.